# Speed up objectDetection with CUDA

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, parallel-processing

I'm trying to learn programming in CUDA. I've created a simple application that makes object detection in avi files with OpenCV, then tried to speed up the detection with CUDA. At this point I'm struggeling how to do it properly. So my plan would be to make the object detection run in different threads to speed up the application. Here's the basic code what I did so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaobjdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudawarping.hpp"
#include "arcos.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::cuda;

void help()
{
    cout << "Usage: ./cascadeclassifier \n\t--cascade <cascade_file>\n\t(<image>|--video <video>|--camera <camera_id>)\n"
        "Using OpenCV version " << CV_VERSION << endl << endl;
}

void convertAndResize(const Mat& src, Mat& gray, Mat& resized, double scale)
{
    if (src.channels() == 3)
    {
        cv::cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        gray = src;
    }

    Size sz(cvRound(gray.cols * scale), cvRound(gray.rows * scale));

    if (scale != 1)
    {
        cv::resize(gray, resized, sz);
    }
    else
    {
        resized = gray;
    }
}

void convertAndResize(const GpuMat& src, GpuMat& gray, GpuMat& resized, double scale)
{
    if (src.channels() == 3)
    {
        cv::cuda::cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        gray = src;
    }

    Size sz(cvRound(gray.cols * scale), cvRound(gray.rows * scale));

    if (scale != 1)
    {
        cv::cuda::resize(gray, resized, sz);
    }
    else
    {
        resized = gray;
    }
}


void matPrint(Mat &img, int lineOffsY, Scalar fontColor, const string &ss)
{
    int fontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX;
    double fontScale = 0.8;
    int fontThickness = 2;
    Size fontSize = cv::getTextSize("T[]", fontFace, fontScale, fontThickness, 0);

    Point org;
    org.x = 1;
    org.y = 3 * fontSize.height * (lineOffsY + 1) / 2;
    putText(img, ss, org, fontFace, fontScale, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 5 * fontThickness / 2, 16);
    putText(img, ss, org, fontFace, fontScale, fontColor, fontThickness, 16);
}


void displayState(Mat &canvas, bool bHelp, bool bGpu, bool bLargestFace, bool bFilter, double fps)
{
    Scalar fontColorRed = Scalar(255, 0, 0);
    Scalar fontColorNV = Scalar(118, 185, 0);

    ostringstream ss;
    ss << "FPS = " << setprecision(1) << fixed << fps;
    matPrint(canvas, 0, fontColorRed, ss.str());
    ss.str("");
    ss << "[" << canvas.cols << "x" << canvas.rows << "], " <<
        (bGpu ? "GPU, " : "CPU, ") <<
        (bLargestFace ? "One, " : "Multi, ") <<
        (bFilter ? "Filter:ON" : "Filter:OFF");
    matPrint(canvas, 1, fontColorRed, ss.str());

    // by Anatoly. MacOS fix. ostringstream(const string&) is a private
    // matPrint(canvas, 2, fontColorNV, ostringstream("Space - switch GPU / CPU"));
    if (bHelp)
    {
        matPrint(canvas, 2, fontColorNV, "Space - switch GPU / CPU");
        matPrint(canvas, 3, fontColorNV, "M - switch One / Multi");
        matPrint(canvas, 4, fontColorNV, "F - toggle rectangles Filter");
        matPrint(canvas, 5, fontColorNV, "H - toggle hotkeys help");
        matPrint(canvas, 6, fontColorNV, "1/Q - increase/decrease scale");
        matPrint(canvas, 7, fontColorNV, "R - rotate on/off");
    }
    else
    {
        matPrint(canvas, 2, fontColorNV, "H - toggle hotkeys help");
    }
}

void elforgat(Mat& src, double fok)
{
    Point2f center(src.cols / 2.0f, src.rows / 2.0f);
    Mat rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, fok, 1.0);
    Mat f;
    cv::warpAffine(src, f, rot, src.size());
    src = f;
}
void elforgat(GpuMat& src, double fok)
{
    Point2f center(src.cols / 2.0f, src.rows / 2.0f);
    Mat rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, fok, 1.0);
    GpuMat f;
    cuda::warpAffine(src, f, rot, src.size());
    src = f;
}

__global__ void detectLyme(cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::CascadeClassifier> &cascade_gpu, bool findLargestObject, double scaleFactor, bool filterRects, cv::Size &minSize, cv::Size &maxSize, cv::cuda::GpuMat &resized_gpu, cv::cuda::GpuMat &facesBuf_gpu, std::vector<cv::Rect> &faces)
{
    cascade_gpu->setFindLargestObject(findLargestObject);
    cascade_gpu->setScaleFactor(1 / scaleFactor);
    cascade_gpu->setMinNeighbors((filterRects || findLargestObject) ? 4 : 0);
    cascade_gpu->setMinObjectSize(minSize);
    cascade_gpu->setMaxObjectSize(maxSize);
    cascade_gpu->detectMultiScale(resized_gpu, facesBuf_gpu);
    cascade_gpu->convert(facesBuf_gpu, faces);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    Mat image;

    string inputName;
    bool isInputImage = false;
    bool isInputVideo = true;
    bool isInputCamera = false;
    Ptr<cuda::CascadeClassifier> cascade_gpu;
    cv::CascadeClassifier cascade_cpu;
    Mat frame, frame_cpu, gray_cpu, resized_cpu, frameDisp;
    vector<Rect> faces;
    GpuMat frame_gpu, gray_gpu, resized_gpu, facesBuf_gpu;
    bool useGPU = true;
    double scaleFactor = 0.9;
    bool findLargestObject = false;
    bool filterRects = true;
    bool forgass = false;
    bool helpScreen = false, run = true;
    double fok = 0;
    TickMeter tm;
    Size minSize = Size(30, 30);
    Size maxSize = Size(34, 34);
    double detectionTime, fps;
    char key;
    string cascadeName = "cascade.xml";

    inputName = "D:\\cicc\\video\\085\\Teszt40\\Teszt_Teszt40_2018-10-09-17-09-25_free_1.avi";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "hun");

    if (getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() == 0)
        return cerr << "No GPU found or the library is compiled without CUDA support" << endl, -1;

    //cuda::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(cv::cuda::getDevice());
    cuda::printCudaDeviceInfo(cv::cuda::getDevice());

    cascade_gpu = cuda::CascadeClassifier::create(cascadeName);
    cout << "name: " << cascade_gpu->getDefaultName() << " size " << cascade_gpu->getClassifierSize() << endl;

    if (!cascade_cpu.load(cascadeName))
        return cerr << "ERROR: Could not load cascade classifier \"" << cascadeName << "\"" << endl, help(), -1;

    if (isInputImage)
    {
        image = imread(inputName);
        CV_Assert(!image.empty());
    }
    else if (isInputVideo)
    {
        capture.open(inputName);
        CV_Assert(capture.isOpened());
    }
    else
    {
        capture.open(atoi(inputName.c_str()));
        CV_Assert(capture.isOpened());
    }
    namedWindow("lajm-e", 1);
    while (run)
    {
        if (isInputCamera || isInputVideo)
        {
            capture >> frame;
            if (frame.empty()) run = false;
        }
        if (run) // end ?
        {
            tm.reset();
            if (useGPU)
            {
                tm.start();
                frame_gpu.upload(image.empty() ? frame : image);
                if (forgass) elforgat(frame_gpu, fok);
                convertAndResize(frame_gpu, gray_gpu, resized_gpu, scaleFactor);
                //detectLyme(cascade_gpu, findLargestObject, scaleFactor, filterRects, minSize, maxSize, resized_gpu, facesBuf_gpu, faces);
                detectLyme<<<1, 256>>>(cascade_gpu, findLargestObject, scaleFactor, filterRects, minSize, maxSize, resized_gpu, facesBuf_gpu, faces);
                tm.stop();
                resized_gpu.download(resized_cpu);
            }
            else
            {
                tm.start();
                (image.empty() ? frame : image).copyTo(frame_cpu);
                convertAndResize(frame_cpu, gray_cpu, resized_cpu, scaleFactor);
                if (forgass) elforgat(resized_cpu, fok);
                cascade_cpu.detectMultiScale(resized_cpu, faces, 1.05,
                    (filterRects || findLargestObject) ? 4 : 0,
                    (findLargestObject ? CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT : 0)
                    | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
                    , minSize, maxSize);
                tm.stop();
            }
            if (forgass) fok++;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i)
                rectangle(resized_cpu, faces[i], Scalar(255));

            detectionTime = tm.getTimeMilli();
            fps = 1000 / detectionTime;

            //print detections to console
            cout << setfill(' ') << setprecision(2);
            cout << setw(6) << fixed << fps << " FPS, " << faces.size() << " det";
            if ((filterRects || findLargestObject) && !faces.empty())
                for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i)
                    cout << ", [" << setw(4) << faces[i].x
                    << ", " << setw(4) << faces[i].y
                    << ", " << setw(4) << faces[i].width
                    << ", " << setw(4) << faces[i].height << "]";
            cout << endl;

            cv::cvtColor(resized_cpu, frameDisp, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
            displayState(frameDisp, helpScreen, useGPU, findLargestObject, filterRects, fps);
            imshow("lajm-e", frameDisp);

            key = (char)waitKey(1);

            switch (key)
            {
            case 27:
                run = false; break;
            case ' ':
                useGPU = !useGPU; break;
            case 'm':   case 'M':
                findLargestObject = !findLargestObject; break;
            case 'f':   case 'F':
                filterRects = !filterRects; break;
            case '1':
                scaleFactor *= 1.05; break;
            case 'q':   case 'Q':
                scaleFactor /= 1.05; break;
            case 'h':   case 'H':
                helpScreen = !helpScreen; break;
            case 'r':   case 'R':
                forgass = !forgass; break;
            }
        } // if run
    } // while (run)
    cout << "File v�ge" << endl;
    //if (key!=27) std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone help me how should I optimize the code to speed it up pls?

Comment: I don't believe the CUDA kernel you have could possibly compile correctly.

Comment: How should I rewrite it to compile correctly?